# Search for matching words in text WITHOUT using HashSet

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that reads a text file, counts the total number of words and determines which words are repeated in the text, and how many times they occur (for simplicity, the text file contains no punctuation). 
I have the following code for finding the repeated words, and how many times they occur.

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
String myString;
String[] line;
// Read words from file, populate array         
while ((myString=br.readLine()) != null) {
    line = myString.split(" ");
        for (String word : line) {
            words.add(word.toLowerCase());  // Ignore case
        }
}
```

The above part reads the text file, and adds every word into an ArrayList, words. The following part uses HashSet to determine which words in the ArrayList words occur more than once. It then prints out these words, followed by a counter indicating the number of occurrences.

```
// Count the occurrences of each word
Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>(words);
for (String key : unique) {
    if (Collections.frequency(words, key) > 1) {
        System.out.println(key + ": " + Collections.frequency(words, key));
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this WITHOUT using HashSet? For example by using two arrays, and comparing them simultaneously? I have tried the following:

```
        numWords = words.size();
        String[] wordArray = new String[numWords];
        String[] newWordArray = new String[wordArray.length];
        String compWord;

        // Find duplicates
        for(int i = 0; i < newWordArray.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < newWordArray.length; j++) {
                if( i != j && newWordArray[i].equals(newWordArray[j])) {
                    compWord = newWordArray[i];
                    System.out.println(compWord);
                }
            }
        }
```

This only prints out the words that occur more than once, as they are read from the file. Which means that it detects repeated words. However, is there a way to get these words in the form "[WORD : timesRepeated]"?

Comment: The `HashSet` solution is the most performant. You do not even need to compute `Collections.frequency`. Just start with an empty HashSet, fill it while iterating through `words` and check if the value is already stored in it.

Comment: You can replace both `ArrayList` + `HashSet` with a single `HashMap<String, Integer>` and use the word count as value.

Comment: You can do it using lets say 2 arraylists. but I don't think that would be as efficient as a hashset.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth had NO idea how to do this! Doing so now. Thanks!

Comment: @aprilrocks92: Awesome!